# Lambda and SQS trigger stops after 15 iterations

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an aws lambda function. It will be triggered using an SQS. The lambda time is 15 mins and SQS queue visibility time is 16 mins. When the lambda is about to get timed out, I will put a continuation key inside the same queue and end the current instance of lambda. A new instance of lambda will start from where it left off using the SQS message. Everything was working fine until lambda put a message to SQS 16th time (execution).

SQS queue shows the message is in flight but lambda is not picking up the message. after 10 retries the message is pushed to DLQ. Also, there is no concurrency issue. What is the reason my lambda is not picking the SQS message after 15 times of execution?

I have been using lambda and SQS for more than 4 years but never faced anything like this. Not sure what I am missing.

Edit:
The message retention in SQS is 4 days.
You can do the following to recreate this issue. Create a sqs named test-sqs with visibility time as 30 seconds and add it as a trigger to a new lambda (lambda timeout is 20 seconds). Also add a dlq to the sqs queue. The following is the lambda code.

```
import json
import boto3
import time
from datetime import datetime
sqsClient = boto3.client('sqs')
SQS_URL = "https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT_NUMBER/test-sqs"
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if ("Records" in event) and (len(event["Records"]) > 0):
        print("Trigger through SQS.")
        for record in event["Records"]:
            event = json.loads(record["body"])
    else:
        print("Triggered manually.")
    print(event)
    start_time = datetime.utcnow()
    print("start", start_time)
    time.sleep(1)
    segment_number = 1
    if "segment_number" in event:
        segment_number = event["segment_number"]

    if segment_number <= 20:
        segment_number += 1
        payload = {
            "segment_number" : segment_number
        }
        sqsClient.send_message(QueueUrl = SQS_URL, MessageBody=json.dumps(payload))
    else:
        print("COMPLETED")
    print("end", datetime.utcnow())
```

Comment: It's hard to debug with this set of info. What's the max retention period? Also when you are saying that you are putting the continuation key, does that mean you push it as a new message or is it considered as a failed try and the message goes for retry? When it goes into DLQ, whats the message body? Whats the last execution result?

Comment: It would appear that your architecture is not appropriate for AWS Lambda. If you frequently have the need to run code for more than 15 minutes, you might consider running the code elsewhere (eg on an Amazon EC2 instance, or in Amazon ECS). Alternatively, break-down the messages into smaller chunks such that processing one message requires less than 15 minutes of processing. The whole process of pushing something onto the queue to continue processing would likely be brittle and is a poor choice of architecture.

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar the max retention period is 4 days. And yes I push a new message to SQS every time. the message in DLQ is the message I get after 15 iteration. Also there is no error. I have edited my answer to recreate the issue.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I understand. But what I have done is a one time process so I thought this should work. My question is why it doesn't work. I have edited my answer for you to recreate. Let me know if you face the same issue

Comment: SQS and Lambda have a recursion control mechanism too. Read [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/detecting-and-stopping-recursive-loops-in-aws-lambda-functions/)

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar wow. I never heard that. It helps. You can add this as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Your code also seems to be assuming that there is only one record passed to the Lambda function. The `for record in event["Records"]` loop will only retrieve the _last_ record passed into the function. If you have configured your function to only receive a maximum batch size of 1, then this is okay.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes I have batch size of 1. Always it is gonna get only 1 message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQS and Lambda have recursion detection mechanisms. If it identifies that the messages are going into an infinite loop then it stops the execution. As of now, it stops on the 16th execution. That's the reason your Lambda is only running 15 times.

When it fails, it will exceed all its max receive count and add the message to DLQ. It emits `RecursiveInvocationsDropped` Cloudwatch metric.

More about it can be found in the article here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/detecting-and-stopping-recursive-loops-in-aws-lambda-functions/

It explains:

1. How it detects loop
2. Where to check for loops
3. How to stop this loop detection
4. Dummy example